# XSJS Get {key:value} paired result from SQL query

Tags: javascript, hana

I am using SAP HANA Studio to create an API which basically does following:

1. Get Request - with parameters
2. **Execute an SQL query** (SQL query is being generated dynamically)
3. **Respond with the result in `{key:value}` pair format.**

**I Tried**:

```
var output = {results: []};
var record = {};
try {
    var query = 'SELECT REGION_ID, REGION FROM \"SOME_TABLE\"';
    var conn = $.db.getConnection();
    var pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    //################### DOUBT ################### 
    var rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
          record.Key1 = rs.getString(1);
          record.Key2 = rs.getString(2);
          output.results.push(record);
    }
    //#############################################

    rs.close();
    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
}

catch (e) {
    $.response.status = $.net.http.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    $.response.setBody(e.message);
}

var body = JSON.stringify(rs);
$.response.contentType = "text/html";
$.response.status = $.net.http.OK;
$.response.setBody(body);
```

**Above code**

In the **DOUBT** part, I am iterating through **`rs`** and assigning values to manually created Keys **`key1, key2, key-n`**. < I DONT WANT THIS >

**I want**

The variable **`rs`** should be like a JSON with key-value pair so I can iterate through it in a way where I don't have to manually create indexes, instead this should come from **DB.**

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will give you the result as an [] of {}, where {} represents a row from the result set. {} Keys are column names and values are actual field values.
You still have to iterate but you do not need to hardcode the keys.
Use [getMetaData](https://help.sap.com/doc/3de842783af24336b6305a3c0223a369/2.0.02/en-US/$.db.ResultSet.html) and corresponding [class](https://help.sap.com/doc/3de842783af24336b6305a3c0223a369/2.0.02/en-US/$.db.ResultSetMetaData.html)

```
function select(sql) {
    var i, object;
    var array = [];
    var label;
    try {
        var runsSQL = $.db.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        var dbReturn = runsSQL.executeQuery();
        var metaData = dbReturn.getMetaData();
        var columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount() + 1;
        while (dbReturn.next()) {
            object = {};
            for (i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
                label = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
                object[label] = dbReturn.getNString(i);
            }
            array.push(object);
        }
        dbReturn.close();
        runsSQL.close();
    } catch (e) {
        return ["error",e];
    }
    return array;
}
$.response.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";     
$.response.setBody(JSON.stringify(select("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM M_TABLES")));
$.response.status = status;
```